# Small Monitors for a Small Room : KRK VXT4 or PMC DB1S ?

Tags: monitoring, monitors, recommendations, gear

Hi All,

A question regarding monitoring(again!)
I went out listening to monitors the other day. I listened to to a variety of models in my price range of 800 - 1000 Swiss francs. I was particularly looking at small monitors as my 'studio' is the shared home office, which also doubles as a library and spare bedroom. It's a crowded room, 4 X 3 m. It has a wooden floor. Oh, and the only place my desk can be is slightly offset in one corner...

I liked the KRK VXT4 A LOT. It seemed very clean, and produced a realistic bass sound will not being to harsh on the high end. What do you guys think of them? 
The salesman also recommended a pair of PMC DB1S, although the store doesn't stock them.
Does anyone here have experience of PMCs?

Also, have I overlooked another option in this price range?

In know that monitoring is a highly subjective issue, but there must be some kind of ball park for small monitors. Just like the headphone thread, every one has their own needs, prefs etc.(I use BeyerDynamic DT770s too...)

I'd like to gather as much advice from you guys, hopefully including speaker names etc that I can listen to on my next test drive day.

Kurt

Update:

Found a shop in Zurich that sells Adam A7X. Will pop by there tommorow morning to check them out. They came recommended by a producer friend, and seem to be universally highly regarded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a big fan of the VXT-4s. That's what I use. The one thing to be aware of with them though is that, for the size, you really can't push 'em too loud. They start to distort on the low end, but looking into the 6's or 8's may not be a bad idea.

But for a small room, they're awesome.

Comment: I've heard that they can distort when pushed too loud. But they do sound good...
I can't monitor too loud anyway as I live in quite an old building, where you hear the neighbours all the time...
But good advice > Taken.

Kurt

Answer (score 2):

hi!
Considering your budget I would go for a couple of KRK V8 or V6. I would try to find something used because it happens very very often to find a good couple of monitors saving 200 euros...I've used the KRK v8 and what shocked me is how much detailed were that speakers! They let you hear all that troubles and mistakes that other speakers hide to you. 
But WHERE you are going to put your monitors is the most important choice. You don't have to think that as you buy them they wil sound good wherever you put them. If you put it in a corner you'll have a response completely unbalanced ad boomy. Be careful!!

Hope it was helpfull :-)

PS take a look on ebay, it will help you much more than me ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I think I will look around on ebay for a bit...About the corner postion, I'll have to make a plan with the room arrangements anyway..